# how to get exports file from power BI as xlsx?

Tags: powerbi

How can I save my exports from BI as **.xlsx** instead of **.csv** ?
when i click on dots and then export data, it show me a tool box that contains only csv file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're exporting from Power BI desktop, which only supports the .csv format.

As David said, if you want to export to Excel, the report needs to be published to a workspace, and then exported from there.

Answer (score 1):

In the workspace, find the dataset you want to export and click the drop down to create a formatted table. From here, create your export and download as .xlsx.
[image]

[image]

Comment: excuse me. i couldn't find this table that you showed me. how can i find that ?!  where is it ?

Comment: Are you looking in your workspace in the power bi service. Click the dots next to your dataset.

Comment: is it possible to let me i send you an email that contains my screen shot from my workspace. in my BI when i click on dots, unfortunately that table not showed to me..

Comment: You can upload a screenshot here.

Comment: ok. i edited my question and add a screen shot to it.

Comment: You need to go to the Power BI service (https://app.powerbi.com/home) and click on the relevant workspace...